# R Stepwise alternative for automatic model selection for panel regression models (plm)

Tags: r, model, dataset, panel, regression

Im running a panel regression (randon effects) and i have several regressor candidates.

```
 X.panel3.form = as.formula(c("value ~ ",paste(X.panel3.cols,collapse="+")))

> X.panel3.form
value ~ SMB + HML + MOM + IBX + EQWO + TERMBZ + BZCDS5Y + COEN + 
    COMP + COMI + COAG + DOL + VIX + SPX + TERMUS
```

Then I run a simple panel regression model

```
fit.plm = plm(X.panel3.form,data=panel,index = c("variable","Date"),  model="random")
```

This would be the full model, but i would like to automatically select models with fewer regressors. similar to a Stepwise procedure.

in facts stepwise with and optimization by AIC would be the best reference in mind, something simple to keep only the more relevant regressors.

the point is that `Step()` function does not work for panel data in R (I believe its because theres no maximum likelyhood estimation for panel models)

so when running the `Step()`, `StepAIC()`(from Mass package)

i got the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("extractAIC") : 
  no applicable method for 'extractAIC' applied to an object of class "c('plm', 'panelmodel')"
```

so my question is: What would be an anternative for automatic model selection in R and a possible simple implementation for panel datasets when using the plm package?

Comment: You have read [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/11849)?

Comment: Roland, tks for the link. I'm aware of the possible problems with automatic model selection approach. But for this preliminary study (and this comes from a boss) I need to limit regressors from a candidate list.

Comment: Still with no luck getting an information criteria to run a automatic model selection...

now im tring to adapt a rlme/lme4 mixed model to accomplish the same thing...

Comment: Hi Alexander, were you able to find answer to your question? I am on the same problem as yours

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution I found at this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65278944/6543127) (full credit to the [original solver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7489539/moritz-schwarz)):

```
    logLik.plm <- function(object){
  out <- -plm::nobs(object) * log(2 * var(object$residuals) * pi)/2 - deviance(object)/(2 * var(object$residuals))
  
  attr(out,"df") <- nobs(object) - object$df.residual
  attr(out,"nobs") <- plm::nobs(summary(object))
  return(out)
}
```

He created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/moritzpschwarz/35fc5be900b99a1a593ab5dd7018ff7b)

Adding this function adds the possibility to calculate AIC and BIC for `plm` objects