# R Extract Log Likelihood from a plm object

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I would like to extract the log likelihood from a `plm` object.

It works fine when using the `logLik` function from the base `stats` package with either `felm` from the `lfe` package or `feols` from the `fixest` package, but not with any `plm` object where the resulting error message is:

```
Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
  no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "c('plm', 'panelmodel')"
```

I checked and `plm` is not a class that is defined for in the `stats` package (see `stats:::`).

Am I missing something conceptually (aware that it's a ML estimation)? As in, why does lfe and fixest make it work and plm does not?  Is there a workaround?

Thanks!

```
library(plm)
library(lfe)
library(fixest)
data("Produc", package = "plm")

# lfe
xx <- felm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp| state + year|0|0,data = Produc)
summary(xx)
logLik(xx)

# fixest
yy <- feols(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp| state + year,data = Produc)
summary(yy)
logLik(yy)

# PLM
zz <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,data = Produc, index = c("state","year"))
summary(zz)
logLik(zz)
```

Comment: A method ´logLik.plm` is simply not defined in the plm package. Quite a variaty of panel models are of class "plm" so if one wants to implement a proper version, one would need to be careful (e.g., error gracefully for non-suitable/not yet implemented models if the logLik needs to calculated in different ways for different models).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

`object` here is a plm object, like `zz` above.

```
logLik.plm <- function(object){
  out <- -plm::nobs(object) * log(2 * var(object$residuals) * pi)/2 - deviance(object)/(2 * var(object$residuals))
  
  attr(out,"df") <- nobs(object) - object$df.residual
  attr(out,"nobs") <- plm::nobs(summary(object))
  return(out)
}
```

This should then also work with the `AIC` command.

I have created a public gist [here](https://gist.github.com/moritzpschwarz/35fc5be900b99a1a593ab5dd7018ff7b).

Comment: `nobs` and `deviance` should work directly on a plm object. Maybe by coincidence, it also works on the associated summary object but that is the less efficient approach.